# Rails 5: update action not working for belongs_to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app current_user needs to update roles for users, who belong to current_user companies. I can get to Edit action, where appropriate selects for particular user role is shown, however **I cannot do Update action - it always stay in Edit action**.

This is what I have in */models/role.rb*:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user, optional: true, inverse_of: :roles
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

enum general: { seller: 1, buyer: 2, seller_buyer: 3}, _suffix: true
enum dashboard: { denied: 0, viewer: 1, editer: 2, creater: 3, deleter: 4}, _suffix: true
# other columns for roles follow #
```

/models/user.rb looks like this:

```
#User has roles
  has_many :roles
  has_many :company_user_roles, through: :companies, source: :user_roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }

# User has many companies
  has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: :accounts
```

In */controllers/common/roles_controller.rb* I have this:

```
class Common::RolesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :get_role, only: [:index, :new, :create, :edit]
 before_action :correct_role, only: [:edit]

def edit
if @roles.any? { |role| role.editer_rights? || role.creater_rights? || role.deleter_rights? }
  @editer_creater_deleter = true
else redirect_to errors_path
end
@role = Role.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@role = Role.find(params[:id])
if @role.update_attributes(role_params)
  flash[:success] = "Role updated!"
  redirect_to dashboard_path
else
  render 'edit'
end

private

def get_role #This is working solution
  @roles = current_user.roles
  end

def correct_role #This is working solution checking if current_user is allowed to access particular role for edit
  redirect_to(errors_path) unless current_user.company_user_roles.where(id: params[:id]).exists?
  end

def role_params #at the end ID of user to whom belongs role is stored
  params.require(:role).permit(:general, :dashboard, //..other role table columns..// , :user_id) 
end
end
```

In */views/common/roles/edit.html.erb* I have this:

```
<%= form_for ([:common, @role]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :general, Role.generals.map { |key, value| [key.humanize, key] } %>
  <%= f.select :dashboard, Role.dashboards.map { |key, value| [key.humanize, key] } %>
  <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>
<% end %>
```

When I press on "Save changes" button, in console I see this:

```
Started GET "/common/roles/3/edit?utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=patch&authenticity_token=ZNVu7jiNOQ6RO7uH7Pe5B4%2BZvf3QKCEFOAZUtCWpNj902dmc3gCG2FULXqkWpU2UIgQrr2ccKdS%2B1iPsv7pqJw%3D%3D&general=buyer&dashboard=editer&commit=Save+changes" for 46.109.175.192 at 2016-10-16 05:24:17 +0000
Processing by Common::RolesController#edit as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZNVu7jiNOQ6RO7uH7Pe5B4+Zvf3QKCEFOAZUtCWpNj902dmc3gCG2FULXqkWpU2UIgQrr2ccKdS+1iPsv7pqJw==", "general"=>"buyer", "dashboard"=>"editer", "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"3"}
```

**Looks like it is not passing "role"=> {...** and after token it shows params which I try to update. As I understand this could be, why Update is not happening.

role *routes.rb* look like this:

```
 namespace :common do
   resources :companies
   resources :roles
 end
```

Index and Edit action for roles works, all actions work for companies.

It looks like role enums are passed correctly, however no Update action at the end. It stays in Edit and loads everything from the start. **How to fix this, please?** Thank you for any help!

Comment: Send the error to `flash[:error]` and you'll be able to at least pinpoint where things could've gone wrong.  From where I'm sitting, it seems like a validation is failing.

Comment: What I see is that it does not go from Edit to Update action at all. Meaning that `flash[:error]` in update action does not show anything. My thought is the same - something might be wrong with validation, however I have commented all validations in `models/role.rb` for now. Any ideas where to check potential validation error?

Comment: @Makoto I tried to do update in console and it looks like when I pass `role = role.update_attributes(dashboard: 1)` it works, however if I pass `role = role.update_attributes(dashboard: viewer)` **it does not**. Probably naive question, but does that mean I have to change view so it pass integer instead of enum string?

Comment: The enum was always an integer, not a string, although I do have to wonder where those specific fields are winding up going.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I know it is integer, however, then the question is if my view is correct as it gets out from database enums in string view? I' ve added screenshot of roles table - please, see above in update.

Comment: @Makoto I checked several times, it looks like problem is not in enums. In console it keeps doing `Started GET` however it should be doing something like `Started PATCH` . I checked routes, where all resources are in place. Do you have any idea where else can I look for error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just be overcomplicating the domain by not modeling it properly.

Using an `enum` for roles on your user model is a perfectly fine when you have a very simple solution where users can only ever have a single role.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:student, :teacher, :other_staff]
end
```

If the domain is more realistic and complex what is usually used is a standard many-to-many relationship between users and roles.

```
class User
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end

# This is join table containing roles assigned to users
class UserRole
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

# This is the "master list" of roles
class Role
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end
```

The simplest possible way to assign/revoke roles would just to be to do it through a normal CRUD controller for your user:

```
<%= form_for( [:admin, @user] ) do |f| %>
  # ...
  <fieldset>
    <%= f.label :roles_ids, 'Roles' %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:roles_ids, Roles.all, :id, :name) %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    respond_with @user
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @user.update(user_params)
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, roles_ids: [])
  end
end
```

Comment: You can additionally scope roles to different kinds of resources etc. Overall its a much more sane and less complex pattern that lets you ovoids turning your `Role` model into a god class and lets you use the standard crud verbs in a meaningful way when granting/revoking. https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

Comment: Thank you, for helping me. I'm trying to implement scenario, when current_user can edit roles for its company (many) users (many). I'm using enums for setting access level for different parts of my app. Do you think I can still use your suggestion above?

Comment: Yes. Its a very flexible pattern. Check out [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) which is very much like this as you may not have to reinvent the wheel from scratch.

Comment: Probably I have not understood something right, but I did not find, how I can store roles in database with Rolify? I mean, how can I allow user to access certain parts of the app with specific rights (e.g., view only)?

Comment: So far my thinking was that I just create roles table, where in single line store with enums all access info for particular user_id. So when user access particular part of app, it gets checked what is access level (denied, view, edit, etc.). User with rights to change other user roles, can do role edit then.

Comment: You would use Rolify together with an authentication library such as [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). You use Rolify to assign roles to users and different resources - and then you use the auth library to setup rules for who gets to do what and enforce those rules.

Comment: For a large domain what you are doing is going to be very unpleasant. You're basically moshing all the role based logic + authorization into a single class.

Comment: So far id did not look so complicated :) I just did access checking before each action... I have quite a standard working query for that. Regarding this issue above, do I get it right that it is basically routes.rb issue? If yes, can you give me a hint what should I change, please?

Comment: I have given you an answer - I'm not going to go into fixing your mess line by line sorry.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I understand. I may sound naive, however my particular question was, why I have "GET", not "PATCH" and part of params are not passing. From my perspective there is relatively simple query for single table update. Please, bear with me as I'm just learning.